# Excel: Inserting data and not autoformat in vba

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

The data I am trying to insert is from a database, and while inserting the data it gets auto formatted to scientific format, is it possible not to auto format it? I don't want it to be in scientific format but in text format

Example that gets auto formatted:
20.E01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the worksheet columns to the appropriate excel type before you assign cell values:

```
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Or to be quick and dirty prefix everything with a `'` to have it interpreted as text.

Comment: Hey again, thanks for the tip. The numberformat did half of the job, because I got a numbered format. I looked further in this and changed the zeros to @ and it now works